# Famo.us on Jetty Server

Tags: embedded-jetty, famo.us, famous-cli

I am looking for the "How To" or proper documentation/tutorials to bring famo.us JavaScript files online from a Java (JRE8) embedded Jetty 9.3 Web Server.

Normally bringing something online, such as JavaScript, with Jetty is a peace of cake but the Famo.us library seems to have its own rules and a kind of 'deploy' application that always sets the output on the Famo.us cloud. I want it locally on disk drive and let Jetty serve the files. I would be interested what deploy does too?

I found [this Famo.us](http://famous.org/get-started.html) explanation to set-up locally (Famo.us CLI/Node.js,glsify, etc) which for development and testing is fine but can't compare to the Jetty performance and architecture.

So I want the best of both worlds, a Jetty embedded server allowing me to have SSL/TLS, HTTP/2.0 (+Push) and Java at server side and JavaScript and Famo.us (or Famo.us/AngularJS) at client side, all from my local server and not from the Famo.us cloud (which I see as a long term liability by the way).

Is there anyone that can point me to how this is best achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `famous deploy` is just a scripting of doing a build of your app into the `public` folder using the `npm run build` script command found in the `package.json` file then publishing the `public` folder to the cloud with a wrapper.

In your case, use `npm run build` to build your application into the `public` folder and publish the `public` folder to your Jetty server the same way you would publish any HTML application.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the 'deploy' did something to the JS code and that part of the deploy cycle was inside the cloud (so what would come out in a local public folder would not be the same as what was in the clouds public folder. Your answers is  all I needed, I know what to do now. Thanks.

Comment: They are wrapping the public folder into an iFrame. No real magic going on. :)